# Django URL not mapping even there is no error why?

Tags: python, django, visual-studio, virtualenv, url-mapping

django startproject folder (URLS.PY):-

```
from django.contrib import adminfrom django.urls import path, include urlpatterns = 
  [
     path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
     path('', include('sub.urls')),
  ]
```

django startapp folder (URLS.PY):-

```
from django.urls import path
  from . import views
  urlpatterns = 
  [
      path('', views.home, name= 'home'),
  ]
```

django startapp folder (VIEWS.PY):-

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
def home(request):
  return HttpResponse("hello world")
```

Comment: What's the URL and what exactly (raw incl. headers) is the response!

Comment: Which url are you trying to get ?

Comment: URL is "sub.url" & Response i want is "hello world". Means , STARTPROJECT is the root folder of django project & STARTAPP(sub) is my subsidiary folder which means SUB is my subsidiary folder, In SUB there are URLS.PY & VIEWS.PY. When i start django server it should first check in root folder URLS.PY, In root URLS.PY there is a path with empty string url (empty string means homepage url right?) when server identify that this is home page url then "sub.urls" will handle that request which means SUB/URLS.PY and in that URLS.PY there is an path that goes toVIEWS.PYin that there is response to show